# Integration warning in scipy's optimization function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to use the [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) function and often get the error

```
packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py:364: IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.
  warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
```

There is a nice solution [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/15961/numerical-evaluation-of-an-elliptic-integral-in-python) on the same issue involving `scipy.integrate.quad`. It is suggested that you can ignore absolute error completely (set `epsabs=0`) and use only relative error.

Is it possible to try this for `least_squares`? I don't explicitly use `quad` in my code but `least_squares` definitely refers to it. There are three tolerance parameters for `least_squares`: `ftol`, `xtol` and `gtol`, but I'm not sure which one the absolute error corresponds to. I'm also not sure how to get `least_squares` to set `epsabs=0` when it uses `quad`.

If you don't think it's possible to adjust the absolute error or that there might be a better way to troubleshoot, I'm also happy to hear suggestions.

(Note: I'm afraid I can't post my code here as it's too long and complicated, but there are some examples on the `least_squares` [help page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) that you can study.)

Answer (score 0):

least_squares does not depend integrate.quad, so the error comes from your code.